# General rule for limit of $a_n^{b_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ denote two series with well defined limits $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n\longrightarrow \infty$.

Is it possible to say following?: $$\lim  (a_n^{b_n}) = (\lim a_n)^{\lim b_n} = a^b$$

If not, can you give a counterexample?

**Edit:** Assume that $a$ positive.

Comment: Well $0^0$ is indeterminate (as is $1^\infty$, though I suppose this doesn’t technically involve convergence of $b_n$). There may also be problems taking $a_n$ to a fractional power if $a_n$ is negative. However, if we assume $a$ is positive and $b_n$ tends to a finite limit, then this follows by continuity; just take the logarithm and you turn the exponent into a multiplier whence you can simply conclude by noting that the limit of a product is the product of the limits.

Comment: In fact the conclusion also generally holds if $a=+\infty$ or $b=\pm\infty.$ The only cases where "we do not know a priori" are when $b\ln a=0\times\pm\infty$ or $\pm\infty\times0,$ i.e. $(b,a)=(0,0^+)$ or $(0,+\infty)$ or $(\pm\infty,1).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That in general does not provide the result.

Assume that $a = -2$ and $b=1/2$  then

$$\lim  (a_n^{b_n}) = (\lim a_n)^{\lim b_n} = a^b =(-2)^{1/2} =\sqrt{-2}$$

Does not make any sense in $\Bbb R.$

> But If $a>0$ then , there a certain rang from which $a_n >0$ and you can therefore write

$$\lim  (a_n^{b_n}) = \lim \exp(b_n\ln a_n =\lim \exp(b\ln a )= a^b $$

If $a_n>0$ and $a=0$ and $b<0$ then $ \ln a_n\to -\infty$ and 
$$\lim  (a_n^{b_n}) = \lim \exp(b_n\ln a_n) =\infty $$

If $a_n>0$ and $a=0$ and $b>0$ then  $ \ln a_n\to -\infty$ and 
$$\lim  (a_n^{b_n}) = \lim \exp(b_n\ln a_n) =0 $$

> If $a_n>0$ and $a=0$ and $b=0$ we o not know  appriory.

Consider 
$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \to 1$$
but 
$$\left(\frac{1}{e^n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} \to e$$

Comment: Thanks, but what if $a$ positive?

Comment: see the edit it is true when a is positif

Comment: @FabianSchn. see all the cases now reload your page

Comment: In fact the conclusion also generally holds if $a=+\infty$ or $b=\pm\infty.$ The only cases where "we do not know a priori" are when $b\ln a=0\times\pm\infty$ or $\pm\infty\times0,$ i.e. $(b,a)=(0,0^+)$ or $(0,+\infty)$ or $(\pm\infty,1).$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\ln{x}$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=A$ and  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}b_n=B$ and we can write $$a_n^{b_n}=e^{b_n\ln{a_n}},$$ where $a_n>0$ and $A>0$ then since $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, the limit is equal to $$e^{B\ln{A}}=A^B.$$

There are cases like $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$ about which we can think separately.